# Программа, обрабатывающая символы строки

Tags: c, строки, кодировка

Написал программу, которая проходит по строке и считает, сколько раз встречается каждый символ. В консоли программа выводит символы (по возрастанию их кодов в кодировке) и их количество повторений. Но проблема в том, что с некоторыми строками возникают проблемы. Так он неверно считывает строку є№ё·¶µґіІ±°Ї®­¬«Є©Ё§¦Ґ¤ и выводит неправильные символы и их подсчёт. Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что эти символы
не входят в кодировку ASCII. Для символов в пределах этой кодировки всё работает, но с символами из unicode уже беда.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char input_string[81000];
    fgets(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin);

    int char_counts[100000] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; input_string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char_counts[(int)input_string[i]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if (char_counts[i] > 0 && (char)i != '\n') {
            printf("%c=%d\n", (char)i, char_counts[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Изменение 04.12.2023:

Использовал библиотеку wchar.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // установка локали
    wchar_t input_string[81000];
    fgetws(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin);

    int char_counts[65536] = { 0 }; // расширение до 65536 для поддержки Unicode

    for (int i = 0; input_string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char_counts[(int)input_string[i]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        if (char_counts[i] > 0 && (wchar_t)i != '\n') {
            wprintf(L"%lc=%d\n", (wchar_t)i, char_counts[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но весь смех в том, что в онлайн компиляторе всё корректно работает, а на моём visual studio вместо некоторых символов печатаются просто пробелы)) Менял настройки кодировок проекта, но это не помогло.
Хочу вообще понять, можно ли решить данную задачу без использования сторонних библиотек, таких как wchar?

Comment: Программа предполагает что код символа в пределах 0-255. Для юникода это не так. Надо всё переписывать.

Comment: Какой стандарт C?

Comment: Укажите OS и в какой кодировке работаете

Comment: Я к примеру работаюв CodeBlocks, частенько пишу консольные приложения. Я изменил кодировку в самом редакторе на 866. По умолчанию он работает в UTF-8 и в консоли "абракадабра". Использовать всякие декодеры и писать setconsole и т.п. нет смысла, если консоль всегда в 866 кодировке выводит. Просто поменяйте в IDE редакторе кодировку на 866 и пишите в ней консольки.

Comment: Если это винда, то так и пишите

Comment: Пишу на Windows 11. В качестве редактора кода использую visual studio. Программа у меня работает пока только для символов ASCII. Мне нужно, чтобы программа могла работать с юникодом. Использовал wchar, но проблема осталась. Помогите переписать программу, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какой стандарт языка C вы используете? В какой кодировке на вход подаётся текст?

Comment: Кодировка - Юникод(UTF-8 без сигнатуры), кодовая страница 65001.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в таблице ASCII 255 кодов. У меня в массиве вроде достаточно места для сохранения всех этих значений. Может дело в настройках самого проекта на visual studio?

Comment: В UTF-8 (кодовая страница 650001) символ `є` представлен парой байтов 209 и 148. Ваша программа обрабатывает каждый байт отдельно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не понимаю, как тогда нужно переделывать код под этот случай.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если использовать getchar(), то он нормально печатает коды символов, но он только для ввода одного символа используется

Comment: Код `є` - 1108 (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0454). `getchar` его правильно возвращает?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Он выводит 243, в таблице ASCII в формате десятичной системы счисления так же стоит.

Comment: Я уже проверку на количество байтов ввёл, ничего не работает(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил изменения

Comment: Читайте о [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Обратите внимание, что по 5-ти старшим битам первого байта, кодирующего utf-символ, можно определить количество байт в этом символе

Answer (score 0):

Код ниже разбирает текст в кодировке UTF8 на отдельные символы. Сделан грубо, но работает. Как пример сойдёт:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool read_utf8_char(int *ord, char s[5]) {
    int chr = getc(stdin);
    if (chr == EOF) {
        return false;
    }
    s[0] = (char)chr;

    int k = 0;
    if (chr >> 7 == 0) {
        *ord = chr;
    } else if (chr >> 5 == 6) {
        k = 1;
        *ord = chr & 31;
    } else if (chr >> 4 == 14) {
        k = 2;
        *ord = chr & 15;
    } else if (chr >> 3 == 30) {
        k = 3;
        *ord = chr & 7;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        int chr = getc(stdin);
        if (chr == EOF) {
            return false;
        }
        s[i + 1] = (char)chr;
        *ord = (*ord << 6) | (chr & 63);
    }
    s[k + 1] = '\0';
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int ord;
    char s[5];
    while (read_utf8_char(&ord, s)) {
        printf("%s %10d %10x\n", ((ord < 32) ? "?" : s), ord, ord);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion dump-chars.c
>
> $ echo "є№ё·¶µґіІ±°Ї®­¬«Є©Ё§¦Ґ¤" | ./a.out
> є       1108        454
> №       8470       2116
> ё       1105        451
> ·        183         b7
> ¶        182         b6
> µ        181         b5
> ґ       1169        491
> і       1110        456
> І       1030        406
> ±        177         b1
> °        176         b0
> Ї       1031        407
> ®        174         ae
> ­        173         ad
> ¬        172         ac
> «        171         ab
> Є       1028        404
> ©        169         a9
> Ё       1025        401
> §        167         a7
> ¦        166         a6
> Ґ       1168        490
> ¤        164         a4
> ?         10          a
> ```

Comment: спасибо за код! Я попытался в нём разобраться и ,вроде, что - то понял. Но, понимаете, я начал изучать C только недавно, и поэтому мне нужно более простое решение, если такое в контексте данной задачи может существовать.

Comment: Спрашиваю потому что я на Linux (где проще), вы на Windows (где сложнее). Этот код у вас работает?

Comment: у меня на Windows код работает. Вот пример вывода:
wer
w        119         77
e        101         65
r        114         72
?         10          a
qwert
q        113         71
w        119         77
e        101         65
r        114         72
t        116         74
?         10          a

Comment: Это всё семибитный ASCII. Он везде работает. Я спрашиваю про символы с кодами больше 128.

Comment: а вот тут не всё так гладко. Вывод: 
¶
?         20         14
?         10          a
¬
?         10          a
?         10          a
‰
%         37         25
?         10          a

Comment: Кодировка в консоли не UTF8 (65001).

Comment: Странно, в настройках проекта я указывал кодировку UTF-8 (65001). Попробовал на онлайн компиляторе. Вывод в онлайн компиляторе:
¶
¶        182         b6
?         10          a
®
®        174         ae
?         10          a
Є
Є       1028        404
?         10          a

Comment: 1. Настройки проекта не имеют отношения к делу. Этот код работает с байтами, никаких символов в нем нет. Байты при любых настройках одинаковы. 2. Важно в каком виде вы подаёте данные на вход. Если файл - убедитесь что он в кодировке UTF8. Если консоль, убедитесь что она правильно сконфигурирована (`chcp 65001`).

Comment: открыл консоль через windws + R, поменял кодировку. Теперь вывод вот такой:
¶
?         20         14
?         10          a
¶
?         20         14
?         10          a
®
R         82         52
?         10          a

Comment: Я же правильно меняю кодировку, если я просто меняю в самой консоли cmd.exe? Потому что, как через сам visual studio менять я ничего дельного не нашёл.

Comment: В редакторе делаете текст с символами. В редакторе убедаетесь, что текст в кодировке UTF8. Печатаете текст в консоли `type <имя файла>`. Убеждаетесь что текст из файла читается в консоли без искажений. Настраиваете консоль так что бы это заработало. Подаёте текст на вход программе, проверяете что вывод ожидаемый.

Comment: спасибо вам и всем другим людям, помогавшим мне. Я разобрался в чём была проблема)

Comment: В чём была проблема?

Comment: Извините, что так долго отвечаю. Редко захожу на форум) Данное задание было домашней работой. Код загружается на онлайн - платформу. У меня не работало из - за настроек консоли и vs. А на сайте всё вывелось корректно.